# Element cloneNode(deep) fails with only undefined error given in console

Tags: javascript, html

I desire to run the method `clondeNode()` to clone a a series of HTML elements sharing the same class but fail with only *undefined* error given in console.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <section class="allEnglishSections">
            <h2>Conditioning</h2>
            <table>
                <tr><th>English</tr></th>
                <tr><td>if</td></tr>
                <tr><td>else</td></tr>
            </table>
        </section>

        <section class="allEnglishSections">
            <h2>Querying</h2>
            <table>
                <tr><th>English</tr></th>
                <tr><td>In plea</td></tr>
                <tr><td>In suggestion</td></tr>
            </table>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the JavaScript I run in console:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".allEnglishSections").forEach((element) => {
    element.cloneNode(deep);
});
```

It fails in the sense that a deep cloning of both existing sections doesn't happen --- no extra two sections get added under the existing two ones.

Why does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements *are* being cloned, but you aren't doing anything with the cloned nodes, so *visually*, nothing happens.

`.cloneNode` returns the cloned node. If you want to append it to the DOM, you have to do so explicitly - the interpreter isn't going to insert it anywhere automatically:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".allEnglishSections").forEach((element) => {
  document.body.appendChild(
    element.cloneNode(true)
  );
});
```

```html
<section class="allEnglishSections">
  <h2>Conditioning</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>English</tr>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td>if</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>else</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>

<section class="allEnglishSections">
  <h2>Querying</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>English</tr>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td>In plea</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>In suggestion</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

(Also note that your current code requires `deep` to be a variable which has `true` assigned to it)

For very similar reasons, the following code won't do anything by itself:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = 'foo';
```

You'd have to insert the div somewhere for it to be made visible to the user.

`undefined` is shown in the console because the last expression evaluated gets printed to the console, but `forEach` returns `undefined`. It's not an error, just an indication that the final expression didn't hold a value.